React GitHub Pages CI/CD Pipeline Seems to Break Site
I have a React website that I am hosting using GitHub Pages. I want to setup a CI/CD pipeline, so that other individuals can update things such as image files without needing to download the codebase and setup the environment, but instead just add/remove image/resource files directly on GitHub. My .yml file for this is as follows:
name: Github Pages Deploy
env:
  CI: false

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "realprod"

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.x]
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install and build
        run: npm install && npm run build
      
      - name: Deploy
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4
        with:
          branch: gh-pages # The branch the action should deploy to.
          folder: build # The folder the action should deploy.        


This workflow runs and builds fine.
Image
However, using this pipeline seems to result in the entire website just turning white/blanking out, similar to when the homepage property is not setup properly-- except that in my codebase, I know the homepage property is setup correctly since it works other then when the pipeline is used.
Package.json file


  "name": " ",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://{}.github.io/{}/",
  "dependencies": {
   },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },



